# direction="right-down" in rich:menuGroup tag?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I have a problem with direction attribute in rich:menuGroup tag :
[pictures : rich:menuItem tag](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-_oiyfmM8BPM/Ux0lcHEv2-I/AAAAAAAAAuI/pDbEZG11xwU/w1044-h472-no/ALTA_CRM1.png).
[image]
I want rich:menuItem moved to position like that pictures. I search a link has example similar my problem :
[Live Demo Richfaces](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dropDownMenu.jsf?c=dropDownMenu)

Here is my code :

```
<rich:dropDownMenu showDelay="250" hideDelay="0" submitMode="none" direction="bottom-right"
    rendered="#{identity.loggedIn and s:hasRole('P01')}">
    <f:facet name="label">Báo cáo</f:facet>
    <rich:menuGroup value="Báo cáo bán hàng" direction="auto">
        <rich:menuItem rendered="#{s:hasRole('P01')}">
            <s:link view="/report/ReportRevenueByItems.xhtml"
                value="Báo cáo doanh thu theo mặt hàng" id="reportRevenueByItem"
                includePageParams="false" propagation="none" />
        </rich:menuItem>
        <rich:menuItem rendered="#{s:hasRole('P01')}">
            <s:link view="/report/ReportRevenueByCustomers.xhtml"
                value="Báo cáo doanh thu theo khách hàng"
                id="reportRevenueByCustomer" includePageParams="false"
                propagation="none" />
        </rich:menuItem>
        <rich:menuItem rendered="#{s:hasRole('P01')}">
            <s:link id="reportDetailSaleByCustomer"
                view="/report/ReportDetailSaleByCustomers.xhtml"
                value="Báo cáo chi tiết bán hàng theo khách hàng"
                propagation="none" />
        </rich:menuItem>
        <rich:menuItem rendered="#{s:hasRole('P01')}">
            <s:link view="/report/ReportDetailContract.xhtml"
                value="Báo cáo chi tiết hợp đồng theo khách hàng"
                id="ReportDetailContract" includePageParams="false"
                propagation="none" />
        </rich:menuItem>
        <rich:menuItem rendered="#{s:hasRole('P01')}">
            <s:link view="/report/ReportDetailsSales.xhtml"
                value="Báo cáo chi tiết hợp đồng theo nhân viên"
                id="reportDetailsSale" includePageParams="false" propagation="none" />
        </rich:menuItem>
        <rich:menuItem rendered="#{s:hasRole('P01')}">
            <s:link view="/report/ReportProductDetailForecast.xhtml"
                value="Báo cáo chi tiết cơ hội" id="reportDetailForecastProduct"
                includePageParams="false" propagation="none" />
        </rich:menuItem>
        <rich:menuItem rendered="#{s:hasRole('P01')}">
            <s:link view="/report/ReportProductForecast.xhtml"
                value="Báo cáo tổng hợp cơ hội" id="reportForecastProduct"
                includePageParams="false" propagation="none" />
        </rich:menuItem>
        <rich:menuItem rendered="#{s:hasRole('P01')}">
            <s:link view="/report/ReportGeneralSales.xhtml"
                value="Báo cáo tổng hợp doanh số theo nhân viên" id="saleReport"
                includePageParams="false" propagation="none" />
        </rich:menuItem>
        <rich:menuItem rendered="#{s:hasRole('P01')}">
            <s:link id="targetUser" view="/report/ReportUserTarget.xhtml"
                value="Báo cáo chỉ tiêu doanh số" propagation="none" />
        </rich:menuItem>
    </rich:menuGroup>
    <rich:menuGroup value="Báo cáo công việc" direction="right-down">
        <rich:menuItem rendered="#{s:hasRole('P01')}">
            <s:link view="/report/ReportSyntheticWorks.xhtml"
                value="Báo cáo tổng hợp công việc" id="syntheticWorksReport"
                includePageParams="false" propagation="none" />
        </rich:menuItem>

        <rich:menuItem rendered="#{s:hasRole('P01')}">
            <s:link view="/report/ReportDetailsWorks.xhtml"
                value="Báo cáo chi tiết công việc" id="reportDetailsWorks"
                includePageParams="false" propagation="none" />
        </rich:menuItem>
    </rich:menuGroup>
    <rich:menuGroup value="Báo cáo công nợ">
        <rich:menuItem rendered="#{s:hasRole('P01')}">
            <s:link view="/report/ReportGeneralDept.xhtml"
                value="Báo cáo tổng hợp công nợ theo khách hàng"
                id="reportGeneralDept" includePageParams="false" propagation="none" />
        </rich:menuItem>
        <rich:menuItem rendered="#{s:hasRole('P01')}">
            <s:link view="/report/ReportGeneralDeptBySupplier.xhtml"
                value="Báo cáo tổng hợp công nợ theo nhà cung cấp"
                id="reportGeneralDeptBySuppier" includePageParams="false"
                propagation="none" />
        </rich:menuItem>
        <rich:menuItem rendered="#{s:hasRole('P01')}">
            <s:link view="/report/ReportDetailDeptBySupplier.xhtml"
                value="Báo cáo chi tiết công nợ theo nhà cung cấp"
                id="reportDetailDeptBySuppier" includePageParams="false"
                propagation="none" />
        </rich:menuItem>
    </rich:menuGroup>
    <rich:menuGroup value="Báo cáo khách hàng">
        <rich:menuItem rendered="#{s:hasRole('P01')}">
            <s:link view="/report/ReportCustomerCare.xhtml"
                value="Báo cáo chăm sóc khách hàng" id="reportCustomerCare"
                includePageParams="false" propagation="none" />
        </rich:menuItem>
        <rich:menuItem rendered="#{s:hasRole('P01')}">
            <s:link view="/report/ReportCustomerNotReSigning.xhtml"
                value="Báo cáo khách hàng không tái ký HĐ"
                id="reportCustomerNotReSigning" includePageParams="false"
                propagation="none" />
        </rich:menuItem>
        <rich:menuItem rendered="#{s:hasRole('P01')}">
            <s:link view="/report/ReportNewCustomer.xhtml"
                value="Báo cáo phát triển khách hàng mới" id="reportNewCustomer"
                includePageParams="false" propagation="none" />
        </rich:menuItem>
        <rich:menuItem rendered="#{s:hasRole('P01')}">
            <s:link view="/report/ExportCustomerListFounding.xhtml"
                value="Báo cáo khách hàng thành lập chẵn"
                id="reportCustomerListFounding" includePageParams="false"
                propagation="none" />
        </rich:menuItem>
    </rich:menuGroup>
    <rich:menuGroup value="Báo cáo kho" direction="right-down">
        <rich:menuItem rendered="#{s:hasRole('UU03')}">
            <s:link view="/report/ReportDetailXNT.xhtml"
                value="Báo cáo chi tiết xuất nhập tồn kho" id="reportDetailXNT"
                includePageParams="false" propagation="none" />
        </rich:menuItem>
        <rich:menuItem rendered="#{s:hasRole('UU03')}">
            <s:link view="/report/ReportInventory.xhtml"
                value="Báo cáo tổng hợp xuất nhập tồn" id="reportInventory"
                includePageParams="false" propagation="none" />
        </rich:menuItem>
    </rich:menuGroup>
</rich:dropDownMenu>
```

How can i move position of rich:menuItem in rich:menuGroup ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using RichFaces 3 the available values for `@direction` are:

> "right", "left", "auto"(Default), "left-down", "left-up", "right-down", "right-up"

See the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/tlddoc/rich/menuGroup.html) for further information.

Comment: Yes. I try to use : <rich:menuGroup value="Báo cáo kho" direction="right-down"> . But it's not work. Maybe i use old richfaces version.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue, adding unique ID to each

> rich:menuGroup

helped. I hope it will solve your issue too. :)